# Unable to connect On-Prem SQL Server to ADF Linked Service

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am trying to connect to On-prem SQL Server ( Microsoft SQL Server)  from ADF self integration run time.
while creating linked service , i am getting below error

Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'DESKTOP-XXX', Database: 'SSIS', User: 'XXXXXX'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
The system could not find the environment option that was entered
Activity ID: f906e552-7d83-4685-a269-819f2f0f6d6b.

Here , i am using authentication type is  "Windows authentication"

How to resolve this issue  , any one  guide me to solve this

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings on the target database/server, is the SHIR hosted in Azure or is it on premise?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my environment and successfully able to connect with on-premises SQL server.

I got similar error when I By mistakenly entered wrong Credentials username and password it throws the same error.

[image]

**To resolve this issue try below steps:**

- Check if your Credential are correct username and password, you can get username by entering `whoami` in command prompt.
  [image]
- Also check if your database is under firewall rule or not if it id then allow it to use SHIR.